# (Javascript) Regex specific characters but excluding

Tags: javascript, regex, string, special-characters

I'm struggle with regex. 
I found some seperated solution for my problem, but doesn't work together.
Now I'm not even sure if this is possible at all.

I have a string like:

`"ÿÿÿÿÿÿBla bla äöüß!ÿÿÿÿÿ\nÿÿÿстрокаÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿQ\u001f\u0001\u0001"`

I want replace all characters

- between 0x00 and 0x1F (until space, non pritable)
- and 0xFF ("ÿ")
- but not 0x0A and 0x0D. (line breaks)

I have both cases seperated:

`// Works great but removes linebreaks.
str = str.replace(/[\x00-\x1F\xFF]+/g, '');`

I want to exclude line breaks.

`//This only extract the line breaks.
str = str.replace(/[^\x0A]/g, '');`

But i want this together / merged. Like that (pseudo)

'''// Incorrect regex. But correct logic.
str = str.replace(/[\x00-\x1F\xFF^\x0A^\x0D]+/g, '');
'''

I have no idea. 
I would be really grateful for constructive help.

Wanted result of string:

`"Bla bla äöüß!\nстрокаQ"`

The string must be compatible with UTF-8. 
I know there is a regex function for removing non pritable character. 
But this also removes umlauts (äöü), cyrillic alphabet and others.

Comment: Try `/[\x00-\x09\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F\xFF]+/g`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
/[\x00-\x09\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F\xFF]+/g
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The point is that you need to re-organize the ranges in the character class, to exclude `\x0A` (newline) and `\x0D` (carriage return).

See demo below:

```js
var s = "ÿÿÿÿÿÿBla bla äöüß!ÿÿÿÿÿ\nÿÿÿстрокаÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿQ\u001f\u0001\u0001";
console.log(s);
var res = s.replace(/[\x00-\x09\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F\xFF]+/g,'');
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Ok, this is a great solution. So simple. Just multiple ranges. It's a kind embarrassing for me. This night was too long. Thanks mate. :)

Comment: This is a workaround. But how to exclude a specific character. This question is not closed. It would be interesting to know it.

Comment: You do not need that, but you may - `/(?:(?![\x0A\x0D])[\x00-\x1F\xFF])+/g`